# NLTK: Tuning LinearSVC classifier accuracy? - Looking for better approaches/advices

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, python, nlp, scikit-learn

**Problem/Main objective/TLDR:** Train a classifier, then feed it a random review and get the correspondent predicted review rating (number of stars from 1 to 5) - only 60% accuracy! :(

I have a big dataset with around 48000 tech product reviews (from many different writers and from different products - here this is not so important (?)) and corresponding ratings (1 to 5 stars) I randomly selected some reviews within each class:

```
1 star: 173 reviews (could not pick 1000 because there were 173)
2 stars: 1000 reviews
3 stars: 1000 reviews
4 stars: 1000 reviews
5 stars: 1000 reviews
```

Total: 4173 reviews - this data is organized in one file (all_reviews_labeled.txt) in tuple format, one review and rating for line:

```
(‘review text’, ‘x star’)
(‘review text’, ‘x star’)
(‘review text’, ‘x star’)
(‘review text’, ‘x star’)
…
```

My 1st “dummie” aproach was:

```
Tokenize review text
POS tagging

Get most frequent bigrams that folowing some POS tags rules for most frequent trigrams (I have seen this rules - using this POS patterns in “Automatic Star-rating Generation from Text Reviews” - pag.7 - paper from Chong-U Lim, Pablo Ortiz and Sang-Woo Jun):

for (w1,t1), (w2,t2), (w3,t3) in nltk.trigrams(text):
    if (t1 == 'JJ' or t1 == 'JJS' or t1 == 'JJR') and (t2 == 'NN' or t2 == 'NNS'):
        bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
        bigrams.append(bi)
    elif (t1 == 'RB' or t1 == 'RBR' or t1 == 'RBS') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJR') and (t3 != 'NN' or t3 != 'NNS'):
        bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
        bigrams.append(bi)
    elif (t1 == 'JJ' or t1 == 'JJS' or t1 == 'JJR') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS') and (t3 != 'NN' or t3 != 'NNS'):
        bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
        bigrams.append(bi)
    elif (t1 == 'NN' or t1 == 'NNS') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS') and (t3 != 'NN' or t3 != 'NNS'):
        bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
        bigrams.append(bi)
    elif (t1 == 'RB' or t1 == 'RBR' or t1 == 'RBS') and (t2 == 'VB' or t2 == 'VBD' or t2 == 'VBN' or t2 == 'VBG'):
        bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
        bigrams.append(bi)
    elif (t1 == 'DT') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS'):
        bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
        bigrams.append(bi)
    elif (t1 == 'VBZ') and (t2 == 'JJ' or t2 == 'JJS' or t2 == 'JJRS'):
        bi = unicode(w1 + ' ' + w2).encode('utf-8')
        bigrams.append(bi)
    else:
        continue

Extract features (here is where I have more doubts - should I only look for this two features?):

features={}
for bigram,freq in word_features:
    features['contains(%s)' % unicode(bigram).encode('utf-8')] = True
    features["count({})".format(unicode(bigram).encode('utf-8'))] = freq
return features

featuresets = [(review_features(review), rating) for (review, rating) in tuples_labeled_reviews]

Splits the training data into training size and testing size (90% training - 10% testing):

numtrain = int(len(tuples_labeled_reviews) * 90 / 100)
train_set, test_set = featuresets[:numtrain], featuresets[numtrain:]

Train SVMc:

classifier = nltk.classify.SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
classifier.train(train_set)

Evaluate the classifier:

errors = 0
correct = 0
for review, rating in test_set:
    tagged_rating = classifier.classify(review)
    if tagged_rating == rating:
        correct += 1
        print("Correct")
        print "Guess: ", tagged_rating
        print "Correct: ", rating
    else:
        errors += 1
```

So far I get only 60% accuracy… What can I do to improve my prediction results? Is something before, some text/reviews preprocessing (like removing stopwords/punctuation?) that is missing? Could you suggest me some other approaches? I am still a bit confused if is really a classification problem or a regression one... :/

Please simple explanations, or give me a link to “machine learning for dummies”, or be my mentor, I promise to learn fast! My background in machine learning/language processing/data mining is very light, I have played a couple of times with weka (Java), but now I need to stick with Python (nltk + scikit-learn)!

**EDIT:**

1. Now I am also extracting unigrams as features, unigrams POS-tagged as 'JJ', 'NN','VB' and 'RB'. It improved a little the accuracy to 65%.
2. I applied also do stemming and lemmatization in text before POS tagging. It improved the accuracy to +70%.

**EDIT 2:**

3. I have feed the classifier all my reviews, the 48000, split into 90% training and 10% testing and the accuracy was 91%.
4. Now I have 32000 new reviews (also labeled) and feed them all for testing and the mean accuracy was 62 % ... my confusion matrix is something like this image below (i divided by equal errors of +1/-1 star point, +2/-2, +3/-3 - because it is just an illustration):

[image]
What is happening? Why accuracy drops so much at 3 and 5 stars?

Answer (score 3):

You might try looking into [sentiment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis).  There was a [kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews) on it, and you might find insight there.

Treating this as either a regression or a classification problem is fair.  Also, it's important to judge your performance against the [proper baselines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis#Evaluation).

Your feature space might not be rich enough for the classes to be linearly separable.  You might do better using an [SVM with a non-linear kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

It also appears you haven't [scaled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) the counts of the bigrams, which is generally helpful for SVMs.

Another thought for an approach would be to apply [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) to the set of documents (reviews) and use the topics as your feature space (you'll have a topic vector per document).

Some places to get python LDA implementations:

[gensim](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim)

[Blei](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html)

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. I don't see how having a topic per document would help to predict rating... but I will have a look on LDA later.

I will try the SVM with a non-linear kernel. thanks

Comment: LDA seeks to cluster tokens (either words or n-grams) that co-occur in documents.  This allows you to learn a lower-dimensional input than, say, word/n-gram frequency.  
If your initial intuition holds true (that the same n-grams will occur in reviews of the same sentiment), then these n-grams will cluster to topics that reflect that sentiment.
Though I haven't seen this implemented in literature, I believe that [labeling your documents](https://frickj.wordpress.com/2015/09/03/a-simple-thought-on-sentiment-analysis/) with a "sentiment token" would help your topics converge.

Comment: With SVM with a non-linear kernel (so far I tried the default 'rbf') i only get 20% accuracy. I will try now with kernel "poly"

Comment: with poly got the same accuracy: around 20%

Comment: I have used all the dataset, the 48000 reviews, 90% training - 10% testing, with LinearSVC, looking at bigrams and adjectives only and get an accuracy of 93%, is it normal? also verified with 10 fold cross validation and mean accuracy is 99.6%...

Comment: how can i show the most informative features within classes?